# How to change parameter type color inside tooltips?

Tags: visual-studio

The default blue color is unreadable on the gray background:

[image]

I couldn't find any option inside Tools > Options > Environment > 'Fonts and Colors' that controlled that particular color.  How do I modify that color?

EDIT:
Looks like either VS or Resharper finally fixed the default color.  It looks like this now, without me having to change anything:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, `string` in C# it's a *keyword*  that means you can simply modify this blue color for all keywords by setting

`Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> Settings for Text Editor -> Keyword -> Item foreground` 
parameter in Visual Studio settings.

Answer (score 1):

There is the resharper extension [EnhancedTooltip](https://github.com/MrJul/ReSharper.EnhancedTooltip/). As far as I know it uses the same colors a the editor window. You can install it from ReSharper -> Extension Manager ... .